# How to add values from Map<T,List<L>> map to List<L>?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a multimap `Map<T,List<L>> map` and I need a list with all the values of the values from the map, namely `List<L>`. With `map.values()` I get a `List<List<L>>`, but thats not what I want.

Does someone know a clean solution without looping?

Comment: If you're on Java 8 you can use Stream

Comment: `map.values().stream().flapMap(l -> l.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: A simple search of "java list of list to list" would bring you to your answer. Search before asking.

Comment: Looked for maps and multimaps :) but sure I should work on my searchskils!

Comment: You should just mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you could collect all `L` values from all `List<L>`s in a single `List<L>` by [`Stream#flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
final List<L> list = map
        // get a Collection<List<L>>
        .values()
        // make a stream from the collection
        .stream()
        // turn each List<L> into a Stream<L> and merge these streams
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        // accumulate the result into a List
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Otherwise, a `for-each` approach with [`Collection#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) can be applied:

```
final List<L> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (final List<L> values : map.values()) {
    list.addAll(values);
}
```

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera That this is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Ok, perhaps It must talk about the java 8 requirement and the stream API

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera, I mentioned about Java 8, and added an alternative method for JDK < 8. Thank you for pointing out it.